# Joining two table entities in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a query like `SELECT * FROM Release_date_type a LEFT JOIN cache_media b on a.id=b.id`. I am new to Spring Data JPA. I don't know how to write entities for Join query. Here is an attempt:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Release_date_type")
public class ReleaseDateType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer release_date_type_id;
    // ...
    @Column(nullable = true) 
    private Integer media_Id;
    // with getters and setters...
}
```

Another entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cache_Media")
public class CacheMedia {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer id;
    // ...
    private Date loadDate; //with the getter and setter ..
}
```

I want to write a `crudRepository` interface such as

```
public interface ReleaseDateTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<ReleaseDateType, Long>{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Release_date_type a LEFT JOIN cache_media b on a.id=b.id")
    public List<ReleaseDateType> FindAllWithDescriptionQuery();
}
```

Comment: You need an association between your entities. Don't store IDs of other entities. Store references to other entities, and use OneToOne, ManyToOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany asociations. Your JPA tutorial (or the Hibernate documentation), should cover that.

Comment: Hi Nizet, Thanks for the quick response, Do you have any Tutorials which can give me more info about association with the entities.

Comment: Search for OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne and ManyToMany in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single

Comment: How to add association between entities? I don't know much but i added as `@OneToMany
    @JoinColumn( name="Description")
    Set<CacheMedia> cacheMedia;' in ReleaseDateType entity. Still issue persists.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not use capital letters in column names... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 118):

For a typical example of employees owning one or more phones, see [this wikibook section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne).

For your specific example, **if you want to do a `one-to-one` relationship, you should change the next code in ReleaseDateType model:**

```
@Column(nullable = true) 
private Integer media_Id;
```

for:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CACHE_MEDIA_ID", nullable=true)
private CacheMedia cacheMedia ;
```

and in CacheMedia model you need to add:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="ReleaseDateType")
private ReleaseDateType releaseDateType;
```

then in your repository you should replace:

```
@Query("Select * from A a  left join B b on a.id=b.id")
public List<ReleaseDateType> FindAllWithDescriptionQuery();
```

by:

```
//In this case a query annotation is not need since spring constructs the query from the method name
public List<ReleaseDateType> findByCacheMedia_Id(Integer id);
```

or by:

```
@Query("FROM ReleaseDateType AS rdt WHERE cm.rdt.cacheMedia.id = ?1")    //This is using a named query method
public List<ReleaseDateType> FindAllWithDescriptionQuery(Integer id);
```

**Or if you prefer to do a `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relation, you should change the next code in ReleaseDateType model:**

```
@Column(nullable = true) 
private Integer media_Id;
```

for:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="ReleaseDateType")
private List<CacheMedia> cacheMedias ;
```

and in CacheMedia model you need to add:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="RELEASE_DATE_TYPE_ID", nullable=true)
private ReleaseDateType releaseDateType;
```

then in your repository you should replace:

```
@Query("Select * from A a  left join B b on a.id=b.id")
public List<ReleaseDateType> FindAllWithDescriptionQuery();
```

by:

```
//In this case a query annotation is not need since spring constructs the query from the method name
public List<ReleaseDateType> findByCacheMedias_Id(Integer id);
```

or by:

```
@Query("FROM ReleaseDateType AS rdt LEFT JOIN rdt.cacheMedias AS cm WHERE cm.id = ?1")    //This is using a named query method
public List<ReleaseDateType> FindAllWithDescriptionQuery(Integer id);
```

Comment: Hi Bigluis,
Are you sure that your answer is correct? I tried it and received it:

  `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: CacheMedia.releaseDateType`

Comment: it looks, you are right, it should be `List<CacheMedia> cachedMedias` instead of `CacheMedia cachedMedia`

Comment: or if you prefer a one-to-one relationship you should use `@OneToOne` in both models

Comment: `public List<ReleaseDateType> findByCacheMedia_Id(Integer id)` What if I have array of cacheMediaId instead of Single Integer in case of one to many or vice versa? @bigluis

Comment: @karmal, you should use `In` at the end of the method method, for example: `public List<ReleaseDateType> findByCacheMedia_IdIn(List<Integer> ids)`

Comment: Luis Vargas are you sure that your answer is correct? For example how do you map ManyToOne association to List<CacheMedia> cacheMedias? Map to List<> possible only for OneToMany association

Comment: sorry, I put them at the contrary. I'll correct the answer. You can take a look into: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne

Comment: @LuisVargas I would clarify that the code substitutions should remove the fields, but not the getters.

Comment: Excuse me, what problem do you solve? "public List<ReleaseDateType> findByCacheMedia_Id(Integer id);" returns only attributes of "ReleaseDateType" which has specific media_id. Whereas topicstarter's "SELECT * FROM Release_date_type a LEFT JOIN cache_media b on a.id=b.id" does another thing altogether, it returns fields from both Release_date_type AND cache_media, for all media_id's. When we filter by Release_date_type.media_id, there is no need to join anything at all.

Comment: `@Query("FROM ReleaseDateType AS rdt WHERE cm.rdt.cacheMedia.id = ?1")`

`public List<ReleaseDateType> FindAllWithDescriptionQuery(Integer id);`
@LuisVargas are you sure that this code works? You didn't show what is `cm` in this case.

Comment: saw first time this syntax ``findByCacheMedias_Id`` solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Query("SELECT rd FROM ReleaseDateType rd, CacheMedia cm WHERE ...")
```

Comment: Be careful, this does a CROSS JOIN between ReleaseDateType and CacheMedia which could yield an unexpected result in some cases (when counting and grouping for instance).

Answer (score -5):

This has been an old question but solution is very simple to that. If you are ever unsure about how to write criterias, joins etc in hibernate then best way is using native queries. This doesn't slow the performance and very useful.  Eq. below

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "your sql query")
returnTypeOfMethod methodName(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Using native queries locks you to a specific database implementation. This prevents you from swapping the database easily.

Comment: @Jezor  I find ORM or JPA very difficult if there are complex joins and tables with 300 or 400 columns. especially in datawarehousing projects.  So  JDBC comes handy.

Comment: `If you are ever unsure about how to write criterias, joins etc in hibernate then best way is` to learn the tools you're using. It's not that hard.