# LEFT JOIN with ON - JPA Repository in Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, repository, left-join

I´m working on a Spring Boot App and struggling on a SQL-Query in my repository.
The query should select all IDs from employees which never postet in my Webapp.

In MySQL Workbench following statement ist working propper and I achive the result like expected.

```
SELECT e.id FROM employees e LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.owner_id = e.id WHERE p.owner_id IS NULL
```

But I cant find out how to write it in my PostRepository which extends a JpaRepository from Spring.
This is the error message

> o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : Invalid path: 'p.owner_id

This is the statment I use in my repository.

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM employees e LEFT JOIN p.posts p ON p.owner_id = e.id WHERE p.owner_id IS NULL")
List<Employee> getEmployeeIdsNeverVoted();
```

I don´t know how to use the "ON" and define the path for it.

Comment: You have a typo in the statement in your respository. `SELECT e FROM employees e` -> `SELECT e.id FROM employees e`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two table entities in Spring Data JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977130/joining-two-table-entities-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Finally I found a solution.
According to my DB I had to change also my DB-Model.

Because hibernate created also always a table which was connected but not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query and your string does not look the same on the table on which you want to join. You have 'posts p' in your query, but p.posts p in your string query and e.id in your query, but e in your string query:

```
SELECT e.id FROM employees e LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.owner_id = e.id WHERE p.owner_id IS NULL
@Query("SELECT e FROM employees e LEFT JOIN p.posts p ON p.owner_id = e.id WHERE p.owner_id IS NULL")
```

Comment: Finally this solved it:

`SELECT e FROM employees e LEFT  JOIN e.posts p GROUP BY e HAVING max(p.timestamp) < ? OR count(p) = 0"`

Comment: Ah, I see. It doesn't need the 'ON'