# Spring Jpa Specification Join table with like

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want use the spring JPA specification join function

This is my code for the tables:

1. Table InStudent
2. Table InParent

   ```
   public static Specification<InStudent> filterByKeywordAndStatus(final String keyword) {
   return (Root<InStudent> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
       List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

       if (StringUtils.hasText(keyword)) {

           predicates.add(
                   cb.or(
                           cb.like(root.get(InStudent_.name), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                           cb.like(root.get(InStudent_.address), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                           cb.like(root.get(InStudent_.phone), "%" + keyword + "%")
                   )
           );
       }

       return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
   };
   ```

   }

How can I join table inStudent and inParent within the specification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two table entities in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977130/joining-two-table-entities-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: You did not include the relationship in your code. Anyway to use a join would be like `Join<InStudent, InParent> parent = root.join(InStudent_.parent);` asuming the field which specifies the relation is `parent`.

Comment: Hello, if the answer helped you don't forget to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (if I've understood you correctly):

```
public static Specification<Student> filterByKeywordAndStatus(String keyword, String parentStatus) {

    return (student, query, cb) -> {

        Join<Student, Parent> joinParent = student.join("parent");

        return cb.and(
                cb.or(
                   cb.like(student.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                   cb.like(student.get("address"), "%" + keyword + "%"),
                   cb.like(student.get("phone"), "%" + keyword + "%")
                ),
                cb.like(joinParent.get("status"), "%" + parentStatus + "%"));
    };
}
```