# Joining two table using hibernate in spring jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to write a join query for joining two tables in Spring Data, using Hibernate.

sql: `select * from a join b on a.B_Id=b.id;`

My classes are as below:

In class `A`, I don't have reference of `B`, I have only B_id. Since its a large project I can't change the class definitions. But need to migrate the join queries to Hibernate.

Any way I can do it?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "a")
    public class A {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    // ...
    private Integer B_Id;
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "b")
    public class B {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    // ...
    }
```

Many to one mapping -> many `A` can have the same `B`.

Comment: Refer https://www.javatpoint.com/jpa-many-to-one-mapping

Comment: Have already mentioned in the question, that I don't have the whole B object in the  A class, to declare the mapping, as opposed in the example mentioned in the link you gave.

Comment: Refer to the link mentioned below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977130/joining-two-table-entities-in-spring-data-jpa