# Fullcalendar data only of logged user

Tags: java, html, spring, fullcalendar

For my project I'm using Fullcalendar and Spring.
The event data from my sql db is divided in these columns: id - doctor_id - patient_id - start - end.

I want to display only event associated to the logged user (data necessaries for login are contained in another sql table named Doctor): now is displaying event of all the users.

This is my controller class:

```
@RestController
class EventController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EventJpaRepository eventRepository;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/allevents", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Event> events() {
        return eventRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/events", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Event> getEventsInRange(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = true) String start, 
                        @RequestParam(value = "end", required = true) String end, @RequestParam(value = "title", required = true) String title) {
    Date startDate = null;
    Date endDate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {
        startDate = inputDateFormat.parse(start);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new BadDateFormatException("bad start date: " + start);
    }

    try {
        endDate = inputDateFormat.parse(end);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new BadDateFormatException("bad end date: " + end);
    }

    LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(startDate.toInstant(),
    ZoneId.systemDefault());

    LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(endDate.toInstant(),
    ZoneId.systemDefault());

    return eventRepository.findByDateBetween(startDateTime, endDateTime); 
    }
}
```

This is the event repository:

```
@Repository
interface EventJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
        
    @Query("select b from Event b where b.start >= ?1 and b.end <= ?2")
    public List<Event> findByDateBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);
    
}
```

And this is the fullcalendar script inside my html page:

```
<script> 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView : 'dayGridMonth',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            locale: 'it',
            editable : false,
            eventLimit : true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events : {
                url : '/allevents',
                type : 'GET',
                error : function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
            }
        });     
        calendar.render();
    });

    
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things your code is missing. Right now, your query returns all events within a time range. To restrict that to just the logged in user, you will need to join the `Doctor` table in the query with the user's id. Not knowing how your session is being stored, or what your `Doctor` table looks like, your query probably needs to be updated something like:

```
@Query("select b from Event b join Doctor d on b.doctor_id=d.id where b.doctorId = ?1 AND b.start >= ?2 and b.end <= ?3")
public List<Event> findByDoctorIdAndDateBetween(Long doctorId, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, String userId);
```

I haven't tested that, but that should get you going in the correct direction.

EDIT:
Sorry, it has been a while since I have written JPA. I have updated the above query, and you will need a

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="doctorId")
List<Event> events;
```

On the `Doctor` object. And a

```
@ManyToOne
Long doctorId
```

On the `Event`. Then you should be able to pass in the doctor_id to the query after retrieving it from your session. This question [Joining two table entities in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977130/joining-two-table-entities-in-spring-data-jpa) gives some good info on how to join tables in JPA queries.

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried but I get an error: Error creating bean with name 'eventController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventJpaRepository' defined in com.labprogettazione.prenotazionemedica.EventJpaRepository. I think that findbydatebetween needs to have only localdatetime interval.

Comment: Doesn't work. It gives me error: ManyToOne … references an unknown entity. I tried changing doctorid in event to: @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Doctor.class)
 @JoinColumn(name="doctorid", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Long doctorid; but it gives me this error: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.labprogettazione.prenotazionemedica.Event.doctorid to com.labprogettazione.prenotazionemedica.Doctor